# Проблема с uwsgi

Tags: сервер, nginx, логирование, uwsgi

Здравствуйте, впервые настраиваю nginx + uwsgi возникла проблема с запуском сервера. В логах uwsgi пишет такое:

```html
Python version: 2.7.3 (default, Mar 13 2014, 11:26:58)  [GCC 4.7.2]
Set PythonHome to /var/www/sportfanat/data/www/sportfanat.com/sportfanatcom-env
*** Python threads support is disabled. You can enable it with --enable-threads ***
Python main interpreter initialized at 0x2541610
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
*** Operational MODE: preforking ***
ImportError: Import by filename is not supported.
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/sportfanat/data/www/sportfanat.com/project/wsgi.py", line 13, in <module>
    from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
ImportError: No module named django.core.wsgi
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
*** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 3374)
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 3375, cores: 1)
spawned uWSGI worker 2 (pid: 3376, cores: 1)
[pid: 3376|app: -1|req: -1/1] 54.36.149.43 () {36 vars in 628 bytes} [Thu Apr  5 20:15:25 2018] GET /bejsbolki/bejsbolki-s-regulirovkoi/?p=bejsbolka-rossiya-art-101565&page=2 => generated 48 bytes in 0 msecs (HTTP/1.1 500) 2 headers in 63 bytes (0 switches on core 0)
```

Настройки uwsgi:

```html
[uwsgi]

# Настройки, связанные с Django
# Корневая папка проекта (полный путь)
chdir           = /var/www/sportfanat/data/www/sportfanat.com/
wsgi-file = /var/www/sportfanat/data/www/sportfanat.com/project/wsgi.py
# Django wsgi файл
module          = project/wsgi.py:application
# полный путь к виртуальному окружению
home            = /var/www/sportfanat/data/www/sportfanat.com/sportfanatcom-env
# общие настройки
# master
master          = true
# максимальное количество процессов
processes       = 2 
# полный путь к файлу сокета
#socket          = 127.0.0.1:8100
socket = /var/www/sportfanat/data/www/sportfanat.com/uwsgi_server.sock
logto = /var/www/sportfanat/data/www/sportfanat.com/logs/uwsgi.log
pidfile=/var/www/sportfanat/data/www/sportfanat.com/uwsgi.pid
touch-reload= /var/www/sportfanat/data/www/sportfanat.com/reload
chmod-socket    = 666
# очищать окружение от служебных файлов uwsgi по завершению
vacuum          = true
plugins=python
```

переустанавливал виртуальное окружение, не помогло

Comment: Опцию virtualenv пропишите для начала

Comment: @andreymal то есть опцию?

Comment: А, это синоним к опции home, тогда не надо, простите. Как именно вы переустанавливали виртуальное окружение?

Comment: @andreymal удалил все в папке с окружением, установил по новой в нее venv и затем из requirements.txt все пакеты поставил

Comment: А конкретные команды без этих абстрактных слов?

Comment: @andreymal 
rm -r env/
virtualenv env
source env/bin/activate
pip install requirements.txt

Comment: Очевидно, каталог `env` и каталог `sportfanatcom-env` — это разные каталоги, в этом наверно и проблема